# Recursive function to build a string from dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm stuck in a problem with a recursive function.

```
hints = ['one','two','three', 'four']

firstCity = 'ROME'

dictionary = { 'ROMEone' : { 'PARIS' : {'hello'} , 'CAIRO': {'money'}, 'MOSCOW': {'racing'} },
           'CAIROtwo': { 'MILAN' : {'in'}},
           'PARIStwo': { 'BERLIN' : {'how'} , 'CANCUN' : {'im'} },
           'MOSCOWtwo': { 'AMSTERDAM' : {'cars'} },
           'BERLINthree': { 'AMSTERDAM' : {'are'} },
           'AMSTERDAMthree' : { 'MILAN' : {'are'} },
           'MILANthree' : { 'PARIS' : {'the'} },
           'CANCUNthree' : { 'LONDON' : {'john'}},
           'AMSTERDAMfour': { 'MILAN' : {'you'} },
           'MILANfour': { 'LONDON' : {'fast'} },
           'PARISfour': { 'CANCUN' : {'bank'} },
           'LONDONfour': { 'FLORENCE' : {'smith'}} }
```

The purpose of the function is to search in the dictionary starting from the "firstCity" and find all the possible phrases that can be extracted from the dictionary.

for each element of the dictionary there are 2 information : the destination (where to look after) and the word (to build the phrase we are looking for)

The result should be:

```
[ ["hello how are you" , "MILAN"],
  ["hello im john smith", 'FLORENCE"],
  ["money in the bank", "CANCUN"],
  ["racing cars are fast", "LONDON"] ]
```

so far I came up with this solution, but It doesn't work properly, may I ask for some suggestions to how to solve this? please!

```
def ex(dictionary, hints, firstCity, words = []):

    for key in dictionary:

        if key == (firstCity + hints[0]):

            for destination in dictionary[key]:

                firstCity = destination

                word = getValue(dictionary[key][destination])
                #getValue simply get the value from the set

                words.append(word)
                if hints[1:] == []:
                    return words
                ex(dictionary, hints[1:], firstCity,words)
    return words
    
def getValue(st):
for el in st:
    if len(st) == 1:
        return el
```

The results of the function with values will be:

```
['hello','how','are','you','are','fast','the','bank','im','john','smith','money','in','the','bank','racing','cars','are','fast','the','bank']
```

Comment: Please update your question with the actual input you are using and the actual output you see.

Comment: What are those top-level keys? Is `ROMEone` actually the string `"ROMEone"` or is it variable name bound to some object of some other type? What are the semantics of the different levels of nesting in the dictionary? It seems like a really awkward data structure for what you want.

Comment: as @quamrana gently said I needed to update the question, wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Although I still don't see how you are calling anything. What is your input?

Comment: the input of it is the firstCity = 'ROME'  and the hints list ['one','two','three', 'four'] and obviously the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
hints = ['one','two','three', 'four']
d = {'ROMEone': {'PARIS': {'hello'}, 'CAIRO': {'money'}, 'MOSCOW': {'racing'}}, 'CAIROtwo': {'MILAN': {'in'}}, 'PARIStwo': {'BERLIN': {'how'}, 'CANCUN': {'im'}}, 'MOSCOWtwo': {'AMSTERDAM': {'cars'}}, 'BERLINthree': {'AMSTERDAM': {'are'}}, 'AMSTERDAMthree': {'MILAN': {'are'}}, 'MILANthree': {'PARIS': {'the'}}, 'CANCUNthree': {'LONDON': {'john'}}, 'AMSTERDAMfour': {'MILAN': {'you'}}, 'MILANfour': {'LONDON': {'fast'}}, 'PARISfour': {'CANCUN': {'bank'}}, 'LONDONfour': {'FLORENCE': {'smith'}}}
def get_vals(s, c = [], t=[]):
   if (k:=next(filter(lambda x:x not in t, hints), None)):
      for a, [b] in d.get(f'{s}{k}', {}).items():
         yield from get_vals(a, c=c+[b], t=t+[k])
   else:
      yield c+[s]

print(list(get_vals('ROME')))
```

Output:

```
[['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'MILAN'], 
 ['hello', 'im', 'john', 'smith', 'FLORENCE'], 
 ['money', 'in', 'the', 'bank', 'CANCUN'], 
 ['racing', 'cars', 'are', 'fast', 'LONDON']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!